# Alternate between two Rails :before_filter(s) on controller action depending on user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

How do I alternate between two before filters depending on the user model of the user accessing the same controller action.

I have two user models User (:database_authenticatable) and another LdapUser (:ldap_authenticatable), and i need them to access the same controller and view on the application. Several view elements and abilities will be unique to each type of user.

I intend to use if else blocks in the view to render user specific elements, and also alternate layouts.

Whats the best approach for such scenarios?

Should they have separate controllers and views?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach if to separate your controllers and your views. If you try to have one controller for 2 models that have differences (view elements, abilities, filters etc ...) you will end up with if-else block scattered all over your application. The will make your code hard to read. Also in the future when you will have to add functionality you will be stuck adding more conditional block and your code will become harder to maintain.

Once you separated your controllers, use the usual RoR strategies to keep your code DRY:

- create a base class that will contain the common methods for your both controllers
- create partial for the common parts of your views
- create service objects for the common abilities of your models
- etc...

So a common before_filter sill sit in your base class, and a specific before_filter in your specific class. Your code will greatly gain readability